# Finding maximum value of a function with parameter

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

How can I find the maximum value (and the corresponding $x$) of the following function with parameter $t$:
$$ f(x) = |x^2-tx + 2t|$$

on a closed interval $x\in[0,1]$?

I tried using `Maximize`, but it doesn't give a result:

```
f[x_] := Abs[x^2 - t x + 2 t]
Maximize[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
(* Maximize[{Abs[2 t - t x + x^2], 0 <= x <= 1}, x] *)
```

Comment: how about `{t->-(3/2)}` ?

Comment: @Nasser t==3/2||t==-3/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Indicating that `t` is real, one succeeds

Solve[Maximize[{RealAbs[2 t - t*x + x^2], 
 0 <= x <= 1 && t >= -Infinity}, x][[1]] == 3]
```

> `{{t -> -(3/2)}, {t -> 3/2}}`

Comment: If I change the t to look like this```t \[Element] Reals``` why can't I find the value?

Comment: @csn899: Sorry, don't understand. Please, present the whole code.

Comment: I got your remark: `Solve[Maximize[{RealAbs[2 t - t*x + x^2], 
     0 <= x <= 1 && t \[Element] Reals}, x][[1]] == 3, t]` produces "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve". Don't know the reason.

Answer (score 5):

`Abs` is a `Complex` Function. We use `Sqrt[x^2]` instead.

```
sol = Maximize[{Sqrt[(x^2 - t*x + 2 t)^2], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
Plot[{sol[[1]], x /. sol[[2]]}, {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Sqrt[(x^2 - t*x + 2 t)^2]` is nothing, but `RealAbs[x^2 - t*x + 2 t]`. `FullSimplify[Sqrt[(x^2 - t*x + 2 t)^2] - RealAbs[x^2 - t*x + 2 t]]` results in `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Numerical approach

```
max[t_?NumericQ] := {t, x /. #[[2]], #[[1]]} &[ NMaximize[{ Abs[x^2 - t x + 2 t], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]]

ParametricPlot[{max[t][[{1, 2}]], max[t][[{1, 3}]]}, {t, -3, 3},PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "max[t]"}]
```

t-dependent maximal value `max[t]` is always at `x==0`or `x==1`!

[image]